# 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. in VS Code, using Code Runner extension

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run some java code in VS Code with the Code Runner extension, but i keep getting this:

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

I checked all the paths and updated the path in VS Code, but it did nothing.

Comment: Have you installed the JDK?

Comment: @stark yes, the jdk1.8.0_60

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246547/path-to-the-compilator-from-the-source-folder/15246586#15246586

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume you are on the Windows System.

First, you might want to add your **jdk path** to window system environment.

[image: point jdk path to system environment]

Then, open your VS Code, and go to **User Settings** located under File -> Preferences -> User Settings.

Add jdk PATH in your VS Code as the following shows.

[image: point jdk PATH in VS Code]

**Important Step**: after all above steps are done, you might want to **restart the VS Code** to let change go in effect.

To test if it works, open Integrated Terminal in VS Code under View (or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (this key is located next to number 1)
Once the terminal shows up and is initialized, type `javac` to verify VS Code recognize the command.

Comment: i am not able to find the workspace settings in vscode

Comment: @gurukiranx can you please try with this link [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

Answer (score 0):

[On Windows]
Although it is called "bin path", the "bin" folder is not supposed to be included in the path. If you do, you get an error and VSCode asks you to remove "bin" from the path in order to solve the issue.

So the path to be added in settings.json should be something like:
"C:/Program Files/YOUR JDK/(YOUR JDK VERSION)-hotspot".

(and not "...-hotspot/bin")

Answer (score -1):

Try and add the jdk bin path to the system environment variable otherwise u need to save the Java code inside the bin folder and compile it from there.

Comment: I have many different projects on my computer and each requires its own JDK version. I do not want to pollute my system path to get an IDE working. There has to be a property in settings.json to point to the JDK or even better one would expect that if java.home points to a valid JDK that VS Code can find javac on its own.